# How would I decode this? Gzip

Tags: gzip

I am looking to unzip this. I know that it is encoded in gzip.

```
var getapi = (
request({
  uri: 'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/SENSITIVEINFO/last_ready_run/data',
  method: 'GET',
  qs: {
    api_key: "SENSITIVEINFO",
    format: "csv",
    headers: { 'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate' }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`request`](https://github.com/request/request) will automatically unzip the response if you specify the appropriate option:

> To accept `gzip`-compressed responses, set the `gzip` option to true.

```
request({
  uri: 'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/SENSITIVEINFO/last_ready_run/data',
  method: 'GET',
  gzip: true,
  qs: {
    api_key: "SENSITIVEINFO",
    format: "csv",
    headers: { 'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate' }
  }
} ...
```